# "Patience et longueur de temps font plus que force ni (?) que rage"

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, coordination

Dans "*Patience et longueur de temps font plus que force ni que rage*", quel est le rôle de "*ni*"? La conjonction *ni* n'est-elle pas employé seulement dans des phrase négatives ou avec *sans*? Qu'est-ce que ça changerait si je la remplaçais par "*et*" comme dans "*Patience et longueur de temps font plus que force et que rage*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dans la première phrase  le *ni* est entendu comme *ou* : c'est soit la force soit la rage (ce n'est *ni* la force *ni* la rage) qui est concernée et elle est plus faible que la patience et le temps qui passe.

Dans la seconde, même additionnées, la force et la rage restent 'perdantes'.

> Patience et longueur de temps [ ne peuvent être vaincues *ni* par la | font plus que ] force *ni* [ par la | que ] rage.

Comment: Semblerait-il naturel d'utiliser _ni_ comme ça dans les conversation quotidiennes?

Comment: @MohammadSanei Non, il s'agit d'un proverbe qui doit donc être concis, utiliser les méthodes de contraction de texte et suivre une prosodie pour être mémorisé facilement, le *ni* insiste en 'réveillant' l'oreille. En revanche  je l'ai souvent entendu remplacé par *et* comme comme dans votre seconde proposition.

Answer (score 6):

L'emploi de *ni* dans une phrase affirmative est actuellement considéré comme un archaïsme, mais il est employé dans la littérature classique.

Le [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ni/54504/difficulte) écrit :

> Ni ne s'emploie plus dans une proposition affirmative, contrairement à l'usage de l'époque classique :
>
> « Patience et longueur de temps / Font plus que force ni que rage » (La Fontaine).
>
> On dirait aujourd'hui : Font plus que force et que rage (ou bien : Font plus que force ou que rage).

ou encore

> L'emploi de ni sans négation ou autre ni qui le précède est archaïque :
>
> « Je serais bien fâché que ce fût à refaire, Ni qu'elle m'envoyât assigner la première » (Racine).

Le [Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/ni) (qui rappelons-le date du XIXème siècle) concède un usage pour les phrases implicitement négatives :

> Ni se dit quelquefois pour et en des phrases qui ont un sens négatif implicite.
>
> « J'ai grande peine à croire ce que vous me dites de madame, ni qu'elle ait pris votre parti contre moi. » [Voiture, Lettres]